# Display/Hide a HTML text when pressed a span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show hidden answer after pressing correct/wrong spans meanwhile hide the question. I have managed to do it but only first answer will appear whichever correct/wrong I press.

Does anyone know how to do it that it will only do the changes in the li of pressed correct/wrong without writing id="" for everything.

I have a code:

```js
var correct = document.querySelectorAll(".correct");
var wrong   = document.querySelectorAll(".wrong");
var answer = document.querySelector(".answer");
var question = document.querySelector(".question");
var display = document.querySelector(".display");
var nodisplay = document.querySelector(".nodisplay");



for (var i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
  correct[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    question.classList.add("nodisplay");
    question.textContent = "";
    answer.classList.remove("answer");
    answer.classList.add("display");
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < wrong.length; i++) {
  wrong[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    question.classList.add("nodisplay");
    question.textContent = "";
    answer.classList.remove("answer");
    answer.classList.add("display");
  });
}
```

```css
.answer {

margin-left: 5px;

display: inline-block;

transition: 0.3s linear;

opacity: 0;

}



.question {

margin-left: 5px;

}



.diplay {

display: inline;

margin-left: 5px;

transition: 0.3s linear;

opacity: 0;

text-align: left;

float: left;

}



.nodisplay {

display: inline-block;

transition: 0.3s linear;

opacity: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="cont">

<h1 class="title">1/4 TEST<i class="fab fa-medapps"></i></h1>



<ul>

<li><span class="question">Question1</span><span class="answer">Correct answer is: </span><span class="yesno correct">NO</span><span class="yesno wrong">YES</span></li>

<li><span class="question">Question2</span><span class="answer">Correct answer is: </span><span class="yesno wrong">NO</span><span class="yesno correct">YES</span></li>

<li><span class="question">Question3</span><span class="answer">Correct answer is: </span><span class="yesno wrong">NO</span><span class="yesno correct">YES</span></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: in your eventListener you can use this to reference the pressed list element

Answer (score 0):

Here is a delegation script

You can take it from there

```js
document.querySelector(".cont").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const li = e.target.closest("li");
  const parentUL = li.closest("ul");
  const yesno = li.querySelector(".yesno")

  const correct = parentUL.querySelectorAll(".correct");
  const wrong = parentUL.querySelectorAll(".wrong");
  const answer = parentUL.querySelector(".answer");
  const question = parentUL.querySelector(".question");
  const display = parentUL.querySelector(".display");
  const nodisplay = parentUL.querySelector(".nodisplay");

  if (yesno.classList.contains("correct")) {
    question.classList.add("nodisplay");
    question.textContent = "Correct";
    answer.classList.remove("answer");
    answer.classList.add("display");
  }

});
```

```css
.answer {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.question {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.diplay {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

.nodisplay {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <h1 class="title">1/4 TEST<i class="fab fa-medapps"></i></h1>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="question">Question1</span><span class="answer">Correct answer is: </span><span class="yesno correct">NO</span><span class="yesno wrong">YES</span></li>
    <li><span class="question">Question2</span><span class="answer">Correct answer is: </span><span class="yesno wrong">NO</span><span class="yesno correct">YES</span></li>
    <li><span class="question">Question3</span><span class="answer">Correct answer is: </span><span class="yesno wrong">NO</span><span class="yesno correct">YES</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @mplungjan, Thank you for working on this, however it doesn't work :( there are no changes when I press the span "yesno"

Comment: Yes there is. If I click the first span, the span changes. Your code is far too big for me to do everything. You can continue with my script

Answer (score 0):

I have done a simple code and you can make changes to suit your needs.

```js
function showStuff(id) {
  document.getElementById("hiddenSpan").style.display = 'block';

}
```

```html
<td class="post">

  <span id="answer1" onclick="showStuff()">
    Click Me and I will make text appear
    </span>

  <span id="hiddenSpan" style="display : none;">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</span>
</td>
```